# How to make a Razor Pages password protected page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I'm trying to make a password protected page.
I've tried doing this by making a page (`Blog.cshtml`) that is only accessible to people who were authenticated after submitting the right password, in the `Password.cs` page.

Password.cshtml:

```html
@page
@model comfrt.world.Pages.Blog.PasswordModel

<form asp-page-handler="Submit">
    Insert password:
    <input type="password" name="Password"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Password.cshtml:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace comfrt.world.Pages.Blog
{
    public class PasswordModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnPostSubmit()
        {
            if (Request.Form["Password"].Equals("<password>"))
            {
                //Authenticate user
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Blog.cshtml

```html
@page
@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        Response.Redirect("./Password");
}
@model comfrt.world.Pages.Blog.BlogModel

<div>
    @* Blog page *@
</div>
```

I've understood that I can do something with authentication, and I've tried different things but I can't seem to figure it out. [The article that keeps coming back](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-6.0) also doesn't really help since the latest update was made in .NET 3.1.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: The article you mentioned in your question is all about Authorization. That's distinct from Authentication. Authentication is about verifying the user is who they say they are. Then Authorization comes afterwards - now that we know *who* you are, are you allowed to do the thing that you're trying to do?  Make sure you keep those distinctions straight.

Comment: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/335/simple-authentication-in-razor-pages-without-a-database